# In laravel how a super user to update a specific user with a user id

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an admin section where super user needs to edit another user details with specific id. Like User::create, how can I update user details?

```
if( empty($user_id) ){
    User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        'role' => $data['role'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),                    
    ]);     
}else{                                                       
    //update user details
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods section updateOrCreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
$user= User::firstOrCreate(
   [
       'unique_field_name' => 'value'
   ], 
   [ 
      'name' => $data['name'],
      'lastname' => $data['lastname'] 
   ]
);
```

unique field name as email or user id or mobile number which are unique fields in your database

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of options:

Here's one:

```
if (empty($user_id) ){
      User::create([
         'name' => $data['name'],
         'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
         'email' => $data['email'],
         'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
         'role' => $data['role'],
         'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),                    
      ]);

} else{                                                       
      User::where('id', $user_id)->update([
         'name' => $data['name'],
         'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
         'email' => $data['email'],
         'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
         'role' => $data['role'],
         'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),                    
      ]);     
}
```

Another way would be:

```
 User::find($user_id)->fill([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
    'role' => $data['role'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),                    
 ])->save();
```

The first way does the update in a single query so is faster but the 2nd way will trigger the model events like `saving` and `updating` so pick what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
User::updateOrCreate(array('user_id' => $user_id), [
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
    'role' => $data['role'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),    
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fields with the same name in the database table columns to fill them without putting them again in eloquent

like that:

```
$user = User::create($request->validated());
```

and in update :

```
$user = User::find($id)->update($request->validated());
```